# Remove file extension from returned list of files

Tags: file, vbscript

I have the below code that obtains a list of txt files from a folder, I would like to remove the .txt from the returned file name, how may I achieve this?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "Notes"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
   For Each objFile in colFiles
   If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "TXT" Then
       document.write objFile.name & "<br>"
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Does `Left(objFile.name, Len(objFile.name)-3)` work?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be a little clearer on where I position that code? I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
...
For Each objFile in colFiles
   If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "TXT" Then
       document.write Left(objFile.name, Len(objFile.name)-4) & "<br>"
   End If
Next
```

According to the docs, [Left()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k(v=vs.84).aspx)

> Returns a specified number of characters from the left side of a string.

You just need to know how many characters to return. Since you already know that the filename ends in `.txt`, you can return all but the **last 4** characters. `Len(objFile.name)` will give you the full length, and you can subtract from there.

Comment: Just incase you are curious, I am making a noting template engine, first step was to grab a list of files and out put them so I can create a selectable table, now I'm going to grab the contents and perform operations. A text file containing [field1] will be replaced by what the user enters into the text field in the app etc.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer to use a function that processes a string, I coded this for my own site once. This function returns the filename without extension, provided there is a "." anywhere in the filename, of course. If not, it simply returns the input filename.

```
Function RemoveFileExtension(inputFileName)
    IF NOT inStr(inputFileName, ".") > 0 THEN
        ' Period not found
        strReturnvalue = inputFileName
    ELSE
        ' Period found. Locate last 
        intPositionRight = 1
        DO WHILE NOT inStr(right(inputFileName, intPositionRight), ".") > 0
            intPositionRight = intPositionRight + 1
        LOOP
        strReturnvalue = left(inputFileName, len(inputFileName) - intPositionRight)
    END IF

    RemoveFileExtension = strReturnvalue
End Function
```

Then you can simply use the function, e.g. like this:

```
For Each objFile in colFiles
    response.write RemoveFileExtension(objFile.name) & "<br>"
Next
```

Happy coding. :)